# What is the elegant solution for unrelated views in MVC web frameworks?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, design-patterns

I've had a problem with the following issue in Rails and ASP.Net MVC.  Often there are multiple widgets of functionality on a page, yet one controller action is supposed to render the page.  Let me illustrate:

Let's say I have a normal e-commerce site, and the menu is made of categories, while the page is to display an group of products.

For the products, let's say I have an action on a controller that looks something like:

```
def product_list
     @products = Products.find_by_category(:name => 'lawnmowers')
end
```

And I have a layout with something like

```
<div id="menu"><%= render :partial => 'menu' %></div>
<div id="content"><%= yield %></div>
```

The products have a view...

```
<%= render :partial => 'product', :collection => @products %>
```

*(note I've ommited the product view as irrelevant)*

And the menu has a partial...

```
<% Category.each {|c| %>
   <%= render :partial => 'menu_node', :locals => { :category => c } %>
<% } %>
```

The line I have a problem with is the "Category.each.do" in the view.  I'm fetching data in the view, as opposed to using variables that were set and bound in the controller.  And it could easily be a more complex method call that produces the menu.

The solutions I've considered are:

-A view model base class that knows how to get various pieces of data.  But you could end up with one of these for each conceptual "section" of the site.
-a local variable that populates at the top of each method (violates DRY)
-the same thing, but in a before_filter call

None of these seem very elegant to me.  I can't help but look at this problem and think that a MVP presenter per view (not screen) is a more elegant solution.

ASP.Net MVC has render action (different from rails render :action), which does address this, but I'm not sure what I think of that solution.

Thoughts?  Solution suggestions?

**Added Note:** 
The answers provided so far are good suggestions.  And they apply to the example I gave, where a menu is likely present in every layout, and is clearly secondary to the product data.

However, what if there is clearly no second class citizen?  Portal type sites commonly have multiple unrelated widgets, in which each is important.

For example, What if this page was displaying weather trends, with widgets for temperature, humidity, and precipitation (and each is a different model and view type).

Comment: excellent question.  I've been struggling with this as well, as my app has the potential for many 'widgets'.  I think each widget should have it's own Controller that knows how to send it it's data, but just not sure how it would be implemented in ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: I tend to use RenderAction in these scenarios, but as you've stated, it's far from perfect.

Comment: DanP, are you referring to rails or asp.net mvc?

Comment: ASP.NET MVC - I tend to put such methods in a "shared" controller and denote the actions with [ChildActionOnly] to make their usage clear(er)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In rails we like to have a concept of thin-controllers, thick-models. So I think you're right to not want to have variables set in the controller.

Also, in order to enable a more-complex method later on, I recommend doing something like:

/app/controllers/application_controller.rb

```
before_filter :add_menu_nodes

def add_menu_nodes
  @menu_nodes = Category.menu_nodes(current_user)
end
```

/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb

```
<%= render :partial=>:menu, :locals=>{:categories=>@menu_nodes} %>
```

/app/models/category.rb

```
def self.menu_nodes(current_user)
  Category.all.order(:name)
end
```

That way in the future you could update Category.menu_nodes with a more complicated solution, based on the current user, if you need.

Comment: thanks, this is a nice write-up.  this is probably the cleanest solution I've seen yet on the rails side.  It does assume this data is needed on on every layout.  And it implies 2nd class data model (categories) which may not be the case.  but i think it's inevitable in mvc that you have that issue.

Answer (score 1):

Forgive me if I butcher the Ruby (or misunderstand your question), but what's wrong with

```
class section_helper
    def menu( section )
        // ...
        menuBuiltAbove
    end
end
```

in the view

```
<%= section_helper.menu( 'section' ) %>
```

?

Comment: that's not a bad suggestion, but it assumes that the menu is a 2nd class citizen to the products.  In the case of a menu, I'd agree.  But there are scenarios where that is not the case.  This is central to why I've seen mvc as great for simple sites, where each page has one clear purpose, but for portal type sites, I think the pattern struggles.

Comment: @Tim Hoolihan I think I see what your problem is.  For portals I have just used jquery to make ajax calls to the controllers and then updated the widget client side.  Maybe that idea helps?

Comment: that's a practical solution that i think is fine, but i think i'm looking for more of a pattern solution.  and on performance critical sites we're adding http requests.